# Product symbol notation for whole set

Tags: notation, products

Is the following notation for a product of all numbers of a set of real numbers strictly wrong?

$$\prod_{x \in X} x$$

I would argue that if the context shows that the multiplication is commutative, the notation is clear and a nice, short way to show what is wanted.

**Context:**

I used the notation in an exam and was deducted half the points (objective was writing down the log likelihood and I'm not a math but CS student). I think I read this notation in quite a few proofs and think the lecturer also used it a few times, but currently I'm failing to find any good examples.

Comment: I would add the requirement that $X$ be finite. Otherwise the product may not be well-defined.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Yes, thank you. In fact the size of the set was given to be a natural number $N$. I guess I'll just write the few symbols more in the next exams and save the trouble :D

Comment: Also, if there is an infinite number of negative values in $X$ then the sign of the product is not well-defined unless the product clearly vanishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfectly fine way of writing this product and it is used quite frequently - but definitely a little bit less frequently than the sum-symbol.

The only caveat (for both) is that it should be clear that this product makes sense: This is surely the case if $X$ is finite.

It will be a lot trickier if $X$ is not finite, as (just as with sums) the order of the factors is not defined, and it could also be the case that it diverges.

---

Some examples where these appear in "the wild":

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_functions
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product#Examples

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad that my "chain of thoughts" seems to be correct. 

If you come across an example, it would be great to have for the exam discussion. I am not sure how / where to look.

Comment: Sure, one of the very well known examples is the Euler product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product#Examples It is infinite, but it should be noted that there is an implicit (natural) order.